# Paginator errors while using elements

Tags: cakephp, pagination, element, paginator

I have news with comments. I'd like to paginate comments but I have the errors like this:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: count [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php, line 646]
```

and of course I don't see numbers, links etc.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Component:

```
public function viewFromNewsId($news_id = null) {
$this->NewsComment->recursive = 0;
$this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => array('NewsComment.news_id' => $news_id, 'NewsComment.is_active' => '1'), 'limit' => 5, 'order' => array('NewsComment.id' => 'desc'));
$newsComments = $this->Paginator->paginate('NewsComment');
if (isset($this->params['requested'])){
return $newsComments;
}
}
```

Element:

```
$newsIdFromUrl = $this->params['pass'][0];
$newsComments = $this->requestAction("newsComments/viewFromNewsId/$newsIdFromUrl");
foreach($newsComments as $newsComment):
$this->App->showNewsComment($newsComment);
endforeach;
echo $this->Paginator->counter('Liczba newsów: {:count} | ');
echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< wstecz', null, null, array('class' => 'disabledText'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ' ', 'before' => ' | ', 'after' => ' | ', 'modulus' => '10'));
echo $this->Paginator->next('dalej >>', null, null, array('class' => 'disabledText'));
echo "<br />";
```

View:
`echo $this->element('newsViewComments');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself ;)

Check this out - maybe someone of you will use this. I know there is a lot of people with the same problem.

Answer:
Just don't use elements, edit view function in your controller like this:

```
public function view($id = null) {
$this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => array('NewsComment.news_id' => $id), 'limit' => 5, 'order' => array('NewsComment.id' => 'desc'));
$newsComments = $this->Paginator->paginate('NewsComment');


$options = array('conditions' => array('News.' . $this->News->primaryKey => $id));
$news = $this->News->find('first', $options);
$this->set(compact('news', 'newsComments'));
}
```

How, you have two variables in your view.ctp:
first one `$news` - with news data like title and text and second one 
`$newsComments` to use with foreach and pagination

But, remember about correct association in models.